# "If you (would/will) all stop shouting, I will try and explain the situation!"

Tags: conditionals

explanation and an example are from [cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if):

> "Will" and "would" can be used in conditional clauses, either with the meaning of "being willing to do something", or to refer to later results:
> **(1)** *If you **would** all stop shouting, I will try and explain the situation!*

I didn't understand why "would" can be used in (1).
Could you tell me please how "would" in (1) relates to the explanation above?

---

an update:
my variant with "will":
**(2)** *If you **will** all stop shouting, I will try and explain the situation!*
What's the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: We use **would** in the if-clause for a **request**.

Comment: It means something like: "If you are willing to stop shouting" - a polite way of saying "shut up".

Comment: @BillyKerr Does "_If you are **willing** to stop shouting_" mean "_If you are **ready** to stop shouting_" ? Thanks.

Comment: If you will stop shouting is **not** willing to stop shouting. It just means that. If you stop shouting now that I am saying this or after I am saying this,

Comment: If you all **will/would (=be good enough to)** stop shouting, I will try and explain the situation!

Comment: @Loviii - Yes, willing to=ready to/prepared to.

Comment: @BillyKerr The thing that makes me really confused is why you say "_you **would**_ =  _you **are** willing to_"???  In terms of grammar it must be: "_you **will**_ =  _you **are** willing to_" and "_you **would**_ =  _you **were** willing to_".

Comment: @Loviii Did you read the definition?  It literally says that "would" can be used in the sense of "being willing to do something"".  This is exactly how I used it.   Would isn't being used as a past tense verb here. It has a past tense form, but in this context it's timeless. It has no sense of having taken place in the past. This is similar to when you say "Would you help me, please?"  This is a common way in English to make polite requests.

Comment: @BillyKerr [thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/would) : "_I told her not to but she **would** do it_." As far as I understand, here "_she **would**_ =  _she **was** willing to_". That is, "_would_" within the same meaning ("be willing to") can be used both instead of the present tense and instead of the past tense, right? Thanks.

Comment: @Lovii - I'm sorry but that isn't the same at all. That has a completely different meaning here, It means "she insisted that she do it".  English is so hard sometimes!

Comment: Keep it simple: "If you stop shouting, I will try **to** explain the situation!"